# listing files from a FTP server directory in groovy

Tags: file, groovy

I wanted to list all the files under a directory which is on public FTP server.

I tried the following

```
new File("ftp://ftp.ex.yyy/a").eachFile() { file->  
  println file.getName()
```

But I get an error

```
URI
  /sample/getStatus/index
Class
  java.io.FileNotFoundException
Message
  /Users/aaaaa/Documents/yyyyy/sample/ftp://ftp.ex.yyy/a
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't treat an FTP site like its a local file. That's why you are getting that exception. Your code is looking on your local file system. After a little googling I found a code snippet for you. I don't *think* you'll be able to easily do this without at least one third party library.

https://gist.github.com/1135043

Comment: Calling `listFiles()` inside this `with` block will give you a list of files :-)